# extract a text from a variable

Tags: bash, variables, conditional-statements

I have a variable named l and it contains a string of characters
for example
echo $l output will be a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3

How do i search for b1 and store it in a new temporary that will be used for condition checking. I cant use awk as the positioning will changed everything.

So my theory will be something like this, getting b1 from that string and i will stored in variable J

$j = b1

if [ $j = 'b1' ]

then

```
 echo "This is a true statment by b1"
```

else

```
     echo "This is a false statement not by b1"
```

fi

Is there a faster way to do this as i think i am duplicating the steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you:

```
l="a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3"
j="b1"
if [[ $l =~ $j ]]; then
    echo "This is a true statement by $j"
else
    echo "This is a false statement by $j"
fi
```

or

```
[[ $l =~ $j ]] && echo "This is a true by $j" || echo "This is false by $j"
```